# Gulp typescript tsconfig with Angular2

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular

I have problem with excluding folders in my app. I'm using a gulp typescript for compilation and tsconfig file. Problem is with node_modules folder, which is still compiling.

**Here is my gulpfile:**

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { typescript: require('typescript') });

gulp.task('tscompile', function () {
var tsResult = tsProject.src("./angular/**/*.ts") // instead of gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

});

**tsconfig content:**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "Scripts"
  ]
}
```

**And my task runner console:**

> angular\chatApp.ts(5,21): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'Scope'.
>   angular\nominationApp.ts(1,21): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'Scope'.
>   angular\notificationApp.ts(1,33): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'Scope'.
>   angular\searchApp.ts(4,21): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'Scope'.
>   angular\teamRegisterApp.ts(1,21): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'Scope'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(77,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(25,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(83,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(83,146): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(96,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(96,147): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(133,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.d.ts(171,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(3,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(4,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(14,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(24,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(25,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.d.ts(436,103): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.d.ts(436,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/compiler.d.ts(12,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/compiler.d.ts(16,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(108,136): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(156,150): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(197,128): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(203,127): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(204,141): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(205,119): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(13,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(14,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(95,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(96,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(97,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(14,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(78,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(7,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(75,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(85,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(35,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(50,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(89,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(94,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(94,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(46,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(47,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(103,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(103,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(143,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(158,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(201,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(206,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(206,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/observable/ForkJoinObservable.d.ts(6,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/observable/ForkJoinObservable.d.ts(7,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromObservable.d.ts(7,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromObservable.d.ts(7,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(9,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   C:/Projects/hrajemevolejbal/HrajemeVolejbal/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(10,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Every gulps are currently in latest version. Angular 2 is beta 7. Can You help me, where is problem? Very thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of your errors can be fixed by referencing the browser.d.ts declaration file in the TypeScript file that calls `bootstrap`:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

For the `Scope` errors, it's harder to say. What `Scope` class/interface are you trying to use?

Comment: Great! It's look fine. Scope was for angular beta 1. I did update and Scope was deleted. Very thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, how does that solve the problem?  If I put that in *any* of my typescript files it seems to solve the compile error.  Is there a place I could put that iin my `tsconfig.json` or `gulpfile.js` so I don't have to have it in my source code?

Comment: Ah, found the answer to my own question, feel free to add it to your answer if you want.

Answer (score 4):

From @MattScarpino's answer, the angular2 package includes the necessary definitions.  Adding this reference line to any of my typescript files seemed to solve the problem:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

I found I could also add the definitions to my list of source files in `gulpfile.js` so the reference wasn't in my typescript files:

```
gulp.task('ts', function (done) {    
    var tsResult = gulp.src([
        'node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts', // ADDED
        "scripts/*.ts"
    ])
      .pipe(ts(tsProject), undefined, ts.reporter.fullReporter());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/appScripts'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In complement to the Matt's answer, you could try the following:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
  typescript: require('typescript')
});

gulp.task('tscompile', function () {
  var tsResult = gulp.src('./app/**/*.ts')
                .pipe(ts(tsProject));
  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

This allows me to compile all the files under my `app` folders.

Answer (score 1):

If compiling just not work with gulp, but in an IDE like Visual Studio, the IDE could be a help to find out what reference you have to add to your bootstrap file.

In my case, the errors looked like this:

`node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(113,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.`

I went to that file in VS, followed the reference (F12) and came to the definition, that was in `typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts`. So I added this as reference in my bootstap typescript file:

`///<reference path="../../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I will also add my version of the gulp task I use:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('build.js.dev', 
function() 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./');
});
```

Note absence of any explicit source files specification.